# How to use winapi SetWinEventHook in python?

Tags: python, winapi

I want to get the handle of every new Dialog which pops up from a specific application.
I understand I should set a hook with [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is in `user32.dll` in windows, but I don't know how to do that in python. Would you give me an example ?

Comment: You might find the [pyHook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page) python wrapper useful.

Comment: it is only useful for mouse and keyboard events and the main logic is hidden in a .pyd file :(

Comment: PyHook is open-source, so you can look at the source code for an example. There are others out there, like [pyconsole](http://code.google.com/p/pyconsole/source/browse/trunk/pyconsole.py?r=5) you can also look at, just use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=python&as_epq=SetWinEventHook&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=). Unless you write or use a C extension module, you're likely going to need to learn about and use several of the built-in `win32xxx` modules and `ctypes.windll.user32`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a very simple example that prints to the console the window text for each dialog that is opened:

```
import sys
import time
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART = 0x0010
WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
ole32 = ctypes.windll.ole32

ole32.CoInitialize(0)

WinEventProcType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    None, 
    ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
    ctypes.wintypes.HWND,
    ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
    ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD
)

def callback(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, idObject, idChild, dwEventThread, dwmsEventTime):
    length = user32.GetWindowTextLengthA(hwnd)
    buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(length + 1)
    user32.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
    print buff.value

WinEventProc = WinEventProcType(callback)

user32.SetWinEventHook.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
hook = user32.SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART,
    EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART,
    0,
    WinEventProc,
    0,
    0,
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
)
if hook == 0:
    print 'SetWinEventHook failed'
    sys.exit(1)

msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
while user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0) != 0:
    user32.TranslateMessageW(msg)
    user32.DispatchMessageW(msg)

user32.UnhookWinEvent(hook)
ole32.CoUninitialize()
```

Comment: nice and clean! Thank you ! One last question: what happens if I don't `UnhookWinEvent` (for example, my app crashes or something)

Comment: The system will clean it up for you. If you need the hook to be active for the entire duration of the process, then you don't need to bother calling `UnhookWinEvent` or `CoUninitialize`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Very satisfying answer!

Comment: Can this be used to monitor every window of all programs?

Comment: @HellOfACode Replace EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART, with EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS where EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS = 0x8005.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx) for various values for the min/max arguments.

Comment: is there a way to listen for hotkeys, specifically Ctrl+C in order to kill the console?