# How to create a window focus listener in windows using win32

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32-process

Is it possible to create a listener that listens every time a window losses  focus in WindowsOS and then runs the callback function? I am using win32api, win32net, wmi, win32gui, win32process. I am using GetActiveWindow()  to get info i need but i am doing this with a sleep timer and i was wondering maybe there is a listner to which i could attach a handler to handle every time the window focus is changed for any window in WindowsOS.

Comment: This is more detailed example of using `SetWinEventHook` in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849564/how-to-use-winapi-setwineventhook-in-python

Answer (score 1):

[SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, 0, HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT )`

```
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK /*hook*/, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
                             LONG /*idObject*/, LONG /*idChild*/, 
                             DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if (event == EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS )
    {
        DbgPrint("%u:%x %p\n", dwmsEventTime, dwEventThread, hwnd);
    }
}
```