# Get hwnd handler of window created

Tags: python, winapi

I am trying to create a window and then obtain the hwnd of the created window.

Currently, I call `subprocess.run("run.exe")` to create the window, then proceed to call `wg.GetForegroundWindow()` to get the hwnd of the foreground window, which should be the new created window. However, this doesn't work well, as the program has to finish opening before it will be detected as the foreground, and the user could change focus in the mean time.

Is there a more consistent way to obtain the hwnd?

EDIT:
Here is what I am doing now with the help of comments below:

```
def create_window():
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    ole32 = ctypes.windll.ole32

    EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE = 0x8000
    def callback(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, idObject, idChild, dwEventThread, dwmsEventTime):
        if is_real_window(hwnd):
            print(get_text(hwnd), "HOOKED")
            user32.UnhookWinEvent(hWinEventHook)
            return hwnd

    WinEventProcType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
        None, 
        ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,
        ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
        ctypes.wintypes.HWND,
        ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
        ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
        ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
        ctypes.wintypes.DWORD
    )

    WinEventProc = WinEventProcType(callback)

    user32.SetWinEventHook.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
    hook = user32.SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE,
        EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE,
        0,
        WinEventProc,
        0,
        0,
        0
    )
    if hook == 0:
        print('SetWinEventHook failed')
        sys.exit(1)

    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()

    x = subprocess.Popen("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe")

    m = user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0)
```

However, this faces two issues. The first, while I can access the hwnd in the callback function, there seems to be no way to actually make create_window return this value. Secondly, the GetMessage window continues to run, even after UnhookWinEvent is called.

What can I do to fix these?

Comment: Do you control the code for both processes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I control the calling python code but not the program being executed

Comment: What are you trying to do with this other app's window?

Comment: I need the hwnd for a large variety of functions. Setting the window style, moving the window, etc. So it is not enough to simply do something to the window as its created; I need the hwnd

Comment: WaitForInputIdle and EnumWindows

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: [WaitForInputIdle doesn't work [...\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33405201/1889329). The accepted answer offers solutions, that do work (WinEvents, or a CBT hook).

Comment: @IInspectable WFII does work but may not be useful here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If calling `WaitForInputIdle` may not be useful (and certainly isn't for what the OP needs), why did you suggest to use it then? Of course the API call works. It just does something else than its name implies (as explained in the Q&A linked to in my previous comment).

Comment: It depends on how the other process is implemented. It may be useful here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The OP doesn't control the program being executed. This was explained prior to your misleading comment. Again, why did you feel the overwhelming need to mislead the OP?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to speak like that. How about some common decency.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is indecent, to provide misleading comments. And given your follow-up comment, this comment seems to have been posted, while you were fully aware of its misleading nature. This is not, what SO is about. Your next comment further tried to mislead the OP: It doesn't just depend on how this other program is implemented. It also depends on how the OS is implemented. And each user's system configuration. You certainly don't control either of these, making `WaitForInputIdle` the wrong tool.

Comment: I was sloppy in my first comment. Agreed. But your tone is despicable. Can't you be civil?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: A 400k+ member knows the difference between *"sloppy"*, and *"rightout wrong"*. You were wrong, and got called on for it. You truly aren't upset about my language or *"tone"*. You are upset, because you were wrong, without anything in your defense. You hate being wrong. That's understandable. Just don't make me pay for your being wrong. I was just the messenger.

Comment: @IInspectable You mean that it's impossible for a program to create a window before `WaitForInputIdle` returns `True`? I didn't think that was the case. Well, I stand corrected. Anyway, there's no excuse for the way you talk to other people. It is loathsome and odious.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is impossible for `WaitForInputIdle` to prevent the OS from creating any threads. It's impossible for `WaitForInputIdle` to prevent 3rd party code from creating remote threads. And it's impossible for `WaitForInputIdle` to travel back in time. All of these are requirements that `WaitForInputIdle` would need to meet, if it were to be useful in solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, that's what I did not know. Thank you for telling me. Could you not have done it with such arrogance, conceit and contempt?

Comment: I attempted to use WinEvents as suggested in the post above, but was not able to get it to work 100%. I edited the post above with details and the problems I am facing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Assigning the `hwnd` received in the callback is a matter of scope.
   The callback function is called asynchronously so it's not possible to return a value;
   instead you can assign the value to a variable in another scope, e.g. to a
   global variable:

   ```
   def callback((hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, ...):
       global HWND
       HWND = hwnd
       ....
   ```
2. Although `GetMessage` seems to run forever, in reality it's awaiting for messages to be
   posted to it's message queue.
   As it is stated in the [Microsoft Docs for the GetMessage function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) :

   > Retrieves a message from the calling thread's message queue. The function dispatches incoming sent messages until a posted message is available for retrieval.

   Before calling the GetMessage remember to store the thread id, e.g. in a global var:

   ```
   def create_window(..):
       global THREAD_ID
       THREAD_ID = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()

       ...
       m = user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0)
   ```

   So any message posted to the thread that installed the hook will make
   GetMessage stop "running" and return a value:

   ```
   def callback(...):
       ...
       win32gui.PostThreadMessage(THREAD_ID, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
       # also valid:
       # win32gui.PostThreadMessage(THREAD_ID, win32con.WM_MOVE, 0, 0)
   ```
3. For unhooking, first is needed the GetMessage loop to exit. The natural
   place for calling `UnhookWinEvent` is after the `GetMessage`, so when the later
   exits, the unhook next will be done:

   ```
   def create_window(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, ...):
       ...
       m = user32.GetMessage(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0)
       user32.UnhookWinEvent( hWinEventHook )
       return HWND
   ```
4. To easily match the `hwnd` received in the callback with it's executable,
   there is the useful `getProcessFileaname` function, that returns the full path
   to the executable (thanks to the author of this gist
   [keturn/trackwindow.py](https://gist.github.com/keturn/6695625#file-trackwindow-py))

   ```
   """
   Much credit to Eric Blade for this:
   https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-July/009381.html
   and David Heffernan:
   http://stackoverflow.com/a/15898768/9585
   """
   import win32con
   import ctypes
   import ctypes.wintypes

   user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
   kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32


   # limited information would be sufficient, but our platform doesn't have it.
   processFlag = getattr(win32con, 'PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION',
                         win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION)

   threadFlag = getattr(win32con, 'THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION',
                        win32con.THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION)


   def getProcessID(dwEventThread, hwnd):
       # It's possible to have a window we can get a PID out of when the thread
       # isn't accessible, but it's also possible to get called with no window,
       # so we have two approaches.

       hThread = kernel32.OpenThread(threadFlag, 0, dwEventThread)

       if hThread:
           try:
               processID = kernel32.GetProcessIdOfThread(hThread)
               if not processID:
                   print("Couldn't get process for thread %s: %s" %
                            (hThread, ctypes.WinError()))
           finally:
               kernel32.CloseHandle(hThread)
       else:
           errors = ["No thread handle for %s: %s" %
                     (dwEventThread, ctypes.WinError(),)]

           if hwnd:
               processID = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
               threadID = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(
                   hwnd, ctypes.byref(processID))
               if threadID != dwEventThread:
                   print("Window thread != event thread? %s != %s" %
                            (threadID, dwEventThread))
               if processID:
                   processID = processID.value
               else:
                   errors.append(
                       "GetWindowThreadProcessID(%s) didn't work either: %s" % (
                       hwnd, ctypes.WinError()))
                   processID = None
           else:
               processID = None

           if not processID:
               for err in errors:
                   print(err)

       return processID


   def getProcessFilename(processID):
       hProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess(processFlag, 0, processID)
       if not hProcess:
           print("OpenProcess(%s) failed: %s" % (processID, ctypes.WinError()))
           return None

       try:
           filenameBufferSize = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(4096)
           filename = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(filenameBufferSize.value)
           kernel32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW(hProcess, 0, ctypes.byref(filename),
                                               ctypes.byref(filenameBufferSize))

           return filename.value
       finally:
           kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess)
   ```