# SetWinEventHook trigger on resize (TrayNotifyWnd) Taskbar (Python)

Tags: python, winapi

I want to hook to the resizing and/or position change of TrayNotifyWnd
I am utilizing what I found here:

[How to use winapi SetWinEventHook in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849564/how-to-use-winapi-setwineventhook-in-python)

Now I do realize that this captures events from all instances, instead of just the ones in the taskbar or to be more precise just `TrayNotifyWnd`, however it should fire **also** when window elements inside `Shell_TrayWnd` like `TrayNotifyWnd` are resized **???**

```
EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND= 0x000B

user32.SetWinEventHook.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
hook = user32.SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND,
    EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND,
    0,
    WinEventProc,
    0,
    0,
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
)
```

It does fire on **every** window being resized, but not TrayNotifyWnd.
I've been testing this by manually resizing TrayNotifyWnd with win32gui.SetWindowPos, hook does not trigger

Windows 11, Python 3.10.7

Comment: This [shouldn't come](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74044578/python-resize-rebarwindow32-with-setwindowpos-win32gui#comment130751061_74044578) as a surprise.

Comment: Fair enough. Here's valuable information then: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683). Make sure you do not confuse *"I don't understand what this is telling me"* with *"This is useless spam"*.